# React js : get foreign key data from .net core entity framework

Tags: reactjs, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using visual studio 2022 react js web app with .net core template. I've sales table in database which uses productId primary key. in react.js I have select menu in which i want to show the product name instead of product id. how could i achieve this?

in component:

```
 // 1 create useStae
    const [sales, setSales] = useState([])

//2 call Api
useEffect(() => {

    fetch("api/sale/GetSales")
        .then(response => { return response.json() })
        .then(responseJson => {

            setSales(responseJson)
        })  
}, [])
```

and in form i have select menu which shows procutId(foreign keys)

```
                        {
                            sales.map((item) => (

                                <option>{ item.productId}</option>

                            ))
                        }
                    </select>
```

in controller

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("GetSales")]
        public IActionResult GetSales()
        {

        NavbaseContext db = new NavbaseContext();
        List<Sale> saleList = db.Sales.ToList();
        
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, saleList);

    }
```

inside sales Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project1.Models;

public partial class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

public int? ProductId { get; set; }

public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

public int? StoreId { get; set; }

public DateTime? DateSold { get; set; }

public virtual Customer? Customer { get; set; }

public virtual Product? Product { get; set; }

public virtual Store? Store { get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show product name instead of id, there are some minor modifications you need to do in each part of the code. Try to follow and understand.

Include `Product` object in your `Sale` class.

Update your API to include the `product name` in the response. You can use LINQ to join the `Sale` and `Product` tables, and select the product name along with other sale properties.

In your component, display `product name` instead of `product id`.

Class

```
public partial class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int? StoreId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateSold { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer? Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Product? Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Store? Store { get; set; }
}
```

API

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetSales")]
public IActionResult GetSales()
{
    NavbaseContext db = new NavbaseContext();

    var saleList = db.Sales
        .Include(s => s.Product) // Include the product object to be able to access its properties
        .Select(s => new { s.Id, s.CustomerId, s.StoreId, s.DateSold, ProductName = s.Product.Name })
        .ToList();

    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, saleList);
}
```

Component

```
<select>
  {sales.map((item) => (
    <option key={item.Id} value={item.Id}>{item.ProductName}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Comment: Glad to hear, just make sure you take a look at LINQ docs, I'm most certain that's the knowledge you were lacking to resolve it by yourself. LINQ is used everywhere in .NET Core, so it's a must learn. A good reference would be the LINQ explanation video by Nick Chapsas, this guy has great explanations on youtube.

Comment: thank you so much for another valuable information.i will definately look into it. I will see the video. thanks again